# How to place personal informations on the left of header in moderncv with classic style

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

I found how to customize my CV created with the `moderncv` and the `classic` style, but I can't found how to put my name a little bit higher and put my personal informations on the left, just below my name, because beside the photo, I don't like it. If the title could be on the middle of the header it would be great.

[image: The header to modify...]

Thanks for your help, don't want to go back to Word it's very interesting to do it in LaTeX.

@Gonzalo Medina : Ok, that's what i wannted :) you're the best thank you, and now if i want to reduce the space between the name and informations, how can i do ? :

[image]

@Gonzalo Medina : Ok, so this is the begining of my .tex file :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[applemac] {inputenc}
\usepackage[french] {babel} 
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}

\photo[100pt]{Photo_cv.jpg}
\firstname{NAME}
\familyname{NAME}
\title{}
\address{ADRESS}{ZIP CODE CITY}    
\mobile{NUMBER}                    
\email{Email}            
\extrainfo{birthdate\\ Nationality- driving license}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

Thanks a lot, really.

Edit 18/12 : @Gonzalo Medina: Hi, Thanks for your answer, it's better now, there still a small space but it's smaller. Just a problem with the title, in my file, if i put a title in \title{}, it's gave me an error (see the photo of the error below) but if i let it empty, it works... don't understand why, maybe a problem of fonts like the error says.

[image: problem]

i think this is this line in the .sty file which gave this error : 
"\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDxyo.png){{\titlefont\text{color2}{#1}}}"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: I think I found the problem. I updated my answer with an improved version.Please let me know if thinks are working as expected now.

Comment: Regarding your new question (anout the extra spacing), once again, I need to see the code you are using (a simple  document like the one in my answer). I ask you for this simple document because I did some tests and couldn't reproduce the problem with the spacing. Please add this simple document as an edit to your question.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new variant; please let me know if this new code does what you need.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina : So, Do you have any solutions please ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility, redefining `\makecvtitle` as defined in `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{10cm}@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet %
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}} % if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile} %
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
     % \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth
}}%
    {}%
 % \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \raggedright\namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}\par\medskip%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{{\centering\titlestyle{\@title}\par}\medskip}%
  %\hfill%
  % detailed information
%  \llap{
%
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
%\end{minipage}\ignorespaces%
%}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{ctanlion}    
\quote{some optional quote}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{Education}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After an edit to the original question, here's a new variant:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[applemac] {inputenc}
\usepackage[french] {babel} 
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{10cm}@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet %
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}} % if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile} %
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
     % \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth
}}%
    {}%
 % \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \raggedright\namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}\par\medskip%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{\vskip-25pt}{{\centering\titlestyle{\@title}\par}\medskip}%
  %\hfill%
  % detailed information
%  \llap{
%
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
%\end{minipage}\ignorespaces%
%}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother

\photo[100pt]{ctanlion}
\firstname{NAME}
\familyname{NAME}
\address{ADRESS}{ZIP CODE CITY}    
\mobile{NUMBER}                    
\email{Email}            
\extrainfo{birthdate\\ Nationality- driving license}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I changed the name of the image used for one of my image files (CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.)

Comment: Sorry i don't understand because my .sty is not like yours :

Comment: @Sangoke you don't really need the `.sty` file. The modifications *shouldn't* be made in the `.sty` file; they can can be made inside your `.tex` file as in my example; anyways, if your `.sty` file is different, you must be using an outdated version of the package, Update your LaTeX system, or at least the relevant packages.

Comment: ok, then i will try directly in my .tex file