# moderncv - how to put personal info under name

Tags: moderncv

I'm new in LaTeX and `moderncv`. I'd like to put my contact info under name but I don't know how. I found [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87281/how-to-place-personal-informations-on-the-left-of-header-in-moderncv-with-classi) similar to mine, but it changes position of the picture. This is my `.tex` file after modification:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{10cm}@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet %
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}} % if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile} %
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
     % \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth
}}%
    {}%
 % \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \raggedright\namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}\par\medskip%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{{\centering\titlestyle{\@title}\par}\medskip}%
  %\hfill%
  % detailed information
%  \llap{
%
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
%\end{minipage}\ignorespaces%
%}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\email{john@doe.org}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

with this result

[image]

but I'd like to put the picture little above and more on the right like in file without modification:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\email{john@doe.org}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much :) and thanks for link to starter guide, surely will be helpful.

Comment: Then remember that you can accept (and upvote) the answer. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 6):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, we have to completely redefine `\makecvhead` to achieve what you want, so add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\\[1.5em]%
    \usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}\fi% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead
\makeatother
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\email{john@doe.org}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\\[1.5em]%
    \usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}\fi% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

With a little bit of hacking inside your code..., I've changed these lines

```
 % \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \raggedright\namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}\par\medskip%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{{\centering\titlestyle{\@title}\par}\medskip}%
  %\hfill%
  % detailed information
%  \llap{
%
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
%\end{minipage}\ignorespaces%
%}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
```

to

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
    \raggedright\namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}\par\medskip%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{{\centering\titlestyle{\@title}\par}\medskip}%
  %\hfill%
  % detailed information
%  \llap{
%
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\raisebox{1em}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}\vspace{2.5em}%

\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
%}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
```

and the result is

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{10cm}@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet %
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}} % if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile} %
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
     % \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth
}}%
    {}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
    \raggedright\namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}\par\medskip%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{{\centering\titlestyle{\@title}\par}\medskip}%
  %\hfill%
  % detailed information
%  \llap{
%
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\raisebox{1em}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}\vspace{2.5em}%

\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
%}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\email{john@doe.org}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```