# How to add personal info in cv title

Tags: moderncv, cv

While preparing my Resumé, the Resumé title looks like

[image: this]

I am getting this with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\firstname{Firstname} 
\familyname{Surname\\ \normalsize MSc. (Mathematics)\quad$\mid$\quad CSIR NET (LS)\\Asst. Professor, Dept. of Mathematics, XYZ College, ABC\\ \phone\,{0000 000 000}\quad\Letter\,\,{abc@example.com}} 
\title{\emph{Resum\'{e}}}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\end{document}
```

Now, to add the personal information in the `\familyname` field is very awkward for me. I am sure there must be something more standard to do this. Also I need to do the following edits there:

1. To write all my personal information in the darker colour accent same as of the `\familyname`
2. To remove/alter the gaps between the *Qualification*, *Designation* and the *Contacts* fields.
3. Also have the word "Resumé" in the same darker colour accent.

I do not want to add any picture to my Resumé. While researching this, I came across with [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151454/moderncv-how-to-put-personal-info-under-name). Here, though the problem is similar to mine, but not exactly so. And being a rookie in LaTeX, I don't really understand the codes.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not sure you want to read this ...

The issue in your case is that you used style `casual`. The standard layout of this style is to print all personal informations into the footer.

Consider this mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\firstname{Firstname} 
%\familyname{%
  %Surname\\
  %\normalsize MSc. (Mathematics)\quad$\mid$\quad CSIR NET (LS)\\
  %Asst. Professor, Dept. of Mathematics, XYZ College, ABC\\ 
  %\phone\,{0000 000 000}\quad\Letter\,\,{abc@example.com}
%} 
%\title{\emph{Resum\'{e}}}


% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

with the usual kind of placing personal informations like

[image: casual cv]

Changing style `casual` to `classic` results in the following cv:

[image: classic cv]

Your request would mean you need a total rewriting of the header. An alternative could be to use style `banking` which results in the following header:

[image: banking cv]

Now the culprit is that you did not show us how you want the other informations of your cv be layouted. All styles does this differently.

So please complete your given code with some anonymous cv informations and show us how they should be layouted. Or decide which style you want to use which nneds only minor changings of title and personal informations.

At the moment your request seems to need a completly rewritting of the code for the title I do not have the time for ... Perhaps it would then be better to use another template for your cv?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already mentioned what I precisely want. I like the dual colour accent in the _firstname_ and the _familyname_. And I do not want to change the alignment as well. Apart from that I am open to use any of the `casual` or `classic` styles as I see that they do not make any difference to the rest of the body. Please give me some codes to include _Qualification_ (in one single line), _Designation_ (in one single line) and _Contact_ (in one single line) fields.